# Why errors getting on WDK include files at the time of build?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, driver

I need to use   for developing my driver . So i need to write IP helper function in Filter.cpp file .

I included these header files in Filter.h File . Like this

**filter.h**

```
#ifndef __FILTER_H__
#define __FILTER_H__

#include "mux/win/ndis62/global.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

class CFilter {

public:

     typedef PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES AddressesType;
 }

 ----

 #endif // __FILTER_H__
```

in **filter.cpp** i am writing code with including Filter.h file also .

But i am using Visual studio 2013 . After Building i got errors like

```
Filter.cpp

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(198): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'CRITICAL_SECTION' [C:\Users\driver\mux\win\ndis62\tun.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(199): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PCRITICAL_SECTION' [C:\Users\driver\mux\win\ndis62\tun.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(202): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG' [C:\Users\driver\mux\win\ndis62\tun.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\minwinbase.h(203): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PCRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG' [C:\Users\driver\mux\win\ndis62\tun.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\errhandlingapi.h(181): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PVECTORED_EXCEPTION_HANDLER' [C:\Users\driver\mux\win\ndis62\tun.vcxproj]
```

I tried to include `windows.h` in filter.h file . But same error . I am also include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um` in 
`properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories` like

```
$(IntDir);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
```

Why this error ? i tried these methods :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

and

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

both gives same errors . How to solve this ? any idea ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: after including these header files , i am getting same error

Comment: Can u share ur filter.cpp?